# How to find a field in the derived classes of a class in java?

Tags: java, reflection

I ask this question because I'm curious. I don't want to actually traverse the derived classes of a class. I know that the method I present here is sloppy this is just a test.

So suppose I have a class (abstract or not):

```
    public class SomeClass {
        // snip....
    }
```

I can easily write a method to walk up the class hierarchy and find a `Field` for example:

```
    private Field extractField(Class<?> type, String fieldName) {
        Field ret = null;
        try {
            ret = type.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Class<?> superclass = type.getSuperclass();
            if (superclass == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing field detected.", e);
            } else {
                ret = extractField(superclass, fieldName);
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Now what can I do If I wish to search for a `Field` in the derived classes of `type`? I did not find anything useful in the java reflection packages.

Comment: Is your question *really* "How do I find all the derived classes?" That's what it sounds like - the `Field` bits feel like a distraction to me.

Comment: I realized that just 1 second before you commented here. I corrected the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no simple way to traverse derived classes as you don't know which classes are derived from a base class.  You can use the [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library to find derived classes. This works by examining the byte code of the classes in your class path, optionally limited to package(s) or pre-indexed.

> Now what can I do If I wish to search for a Field in the derived classes of type?

Once you have found the derived classes you can examine these in the same way.

Comment: Can you imagine a problem where the **only** solution is this (traversing derived classes)? Did you use this functionality in an application you wrote?

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to examine the fields of all derived classes so I can't give you a more inspired answer ;) I suggest you avoid traversing dervived classes as loading such classes can have side effects e.g. static initialiser blocks run.

Comment: Ok that's what I thought too.